# Drivers for Sony Vaio VGN-FS920

Tags: 11.10, vaio

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on A Sony Vaio VGN-FS920. I need to know how to install drivers for the touchpad and basicaly general operating drivers. I know you can go to Sony's site and get them but they are all for Windows XP. What can I do. I really like Ubuntu and I think it is the best system for this older model computer. It just has some bugs with it that I think are caused because I need new drivers.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In general there are no "drivers" for Ubuntu in the same sense as for Windows. So going to SONY's web site would not help.

In Ubuntu most of the "drivers" are embedded in the Linux kernel itself. The rest are either left out as optional loadable "modules" or are proprietary drivers that cannot be embedded into the Linux kernel. One such example is the NVIDIA graphics driver. It is provided by NVIDIA in binary form only and therefore it cannot be embedded in the Linux kernel.

That said most of these proprietary drivers can be installed using the "Additional Drivers" a.k.a. "jockey" utility found in your default installation. It will scan your system for potential candidate devices for which there is a proprietary driver available and offer you to activate them.

To use the utility:

1. Open the dash by hitting the Super key or clicking on the "Ubuntu" button usually located in the top slot of the launcher.
2. Search for "Additional".
3. Launch the "Additional Drivers" application.

Once in the utility, wait for it to scan your system and install any drivers that you like if it found any.

If the utility does not find anything and/or installing any proprietary driver does not help your issues, you will have to ask for a solution of a specific issue you are having with Ubuntu on your laptop in a separate question.